# MySQL Count Values (using group by?) based on 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Ok, its late,  so this might be obvious, but I'm having some trouble with it.

I have 2 tables.

```
Filter
-

id
catId
value
```

All the values should be unique so this query gets all the values and their "id"s

```
select value as prodVal, id 
from Filter 
where catId = 7 group by prodVal
```

That query returns this ...

```
id = 82, value = 'filter1'
id = 92, value = 'filter2'
etc.. etc...
```

I need to then take that list of "id"s and process it on the second table, which is

```
prodFilters
-
id
filterId
productId
```

So I need to count how many occurences of "FilterID" exists in "prodFilters"  for every "ID" that was pulled up in the previous query ...

FOREACH (id from previous query) DO THIS ...

```
select count(*) from prodFilters 
where filterId = {value from last query} 
group by filterId
```

Is there any way to get this all accomplished through one query, rather than running the first query and then running multiple queries after it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: not sure I understand the reason to use a `group by` without a aggregation function? AFAIK it's not possible to do that

Comment: @Sathya: `SELECT f FROM a GROUP BY f` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT f FROM a`. And yes, it's possible.

Comment: @ypercube While I know that's possible, I didn't know MySQL allowed for `SELECT x,y from a GROUP BY z` same as `SELECT DISTINCT x,y from a`? Oracle would throw an error there

Comment: @Sathya; You are right, MySQL allows this `SELECT x,y from a GROUP BY z` (under default, no strict ANSI settings) which is not allowed in other DBMS. If `z` is Unique or Primary Key then it's equivalent to `SELECT x,y from a GROUP BY z,x,y`

Comment: Otherwise it returns indeterminate results, more like `SELECT ONE_RANDOM(x),ONE_RANDOM(y) from a GROUP BY z`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `IN` clause

```
SELECT filterid, COUNT(*)
FROM   prodfilters
WHERE  filterid IN (SELECT id 
                    from Filter 
                    WHERE  catid = 7 
                    group by prodVal)
GROUP  BY filterid
```

Comment: There are 2 tables, i only see one in this query.   And no, it doesn't work how I want it to.

Comment: @BrianPatterson Would be helpful to have some sample data on both tables. Try now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select f.value as prodVal, f.id,  Count(pf.filterId) as 'Filter Count'
From Filter f
inner join prodFilters pf on f.id = pf.filterId
where f.catId = 7 
group by pf.filterId
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select Filter.value as prodVal, Filter.id , count(filterId) from prodFilters, Filter where filterId IN (select id from Filter where catId = 7) group by filterId
```

Comment: This returns a count of 170 where it should be 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select count(filterid) 
from prodfilters where id in (select value as prodVal, id 
    from Filter 
    where catId = 7 group by prodVal) as temp 
    group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT catId, COUNT(*)
FROM   prodFilters
WHERE  catId IN (SELECT id from Filter
                    WHERE  catId = 1 )
GROUP  BY catId
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  In the end, I worked the answer out on my own, based on some of your suggestions.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(p.id) , p.filderId from prodFilters as p , filter as f
where p.filterId = f.id and f.catId = 7 
group by p.filterId
```

I think this would work, as each catId , value is unique field

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
With A as {

select value as prodVal, id 
from Filter 
where catId = 7 group by prodVal

}
select count(*) from prodFilters 
where filterId in {A.id} 
group by filterId
```

This works fine in oracle but not sure about MySQL

Mysql:

```
SELECT   COUNT (*)
    FROM prodfilters t
         JOIN
         (SELECT   VALUE AS prodval, ID
              FROM filter
             WHERE catid = 7
          GROUP BY prodval) ta ON ta.ID = t.filterid
GROUP BY filterid
```

Comment: It would not work in any other DBMS because of the `GROUP BY prodVal` and `SELECT id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
select COUNT(*) from  filter as f left outer join prodFilter as p on f.Id = p.filterId
```